# Second sql call depends on another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm making a stored procedure where several table inserts and updates are dependent on the inserts before them. Do I need to do anything to ensure those operations finish, ( like a commit), or are inserts in a stored procedure calls always done and completed in order and I'm worrying about nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're worrying about nothing, the only scenario where you would need to be concerned is if say you were creating a permanent table (non-temp/non-variable table) and were going to do inserts into it afterwards. To get past the run-time error indicating the table does not exist you would have to put a "GO" after the table creation, but before the record insertion. You can always use a "GO" command to ensure all procedural commands up to that point are completed before proceeding with any code thereafter, but it is not necessary in most scenarios. If you perform an insert and then perform an update immediately after the update logic should not be evaluated until after the insert has completed, but if you want to be extra extra sure simply pop in a "GO" in between them and then there can be no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

If you have several statements and want to be sure that either all of them complete, or none of them, then you should use a transaction. There are many reasons an insert or update statement can fail, so it is a good idea to check.

use `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before your statements, and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` after them. In the case that you want to cancel any work done in the batch so far, you can also call `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`.

Wrap these statements in `TRY/CATCH` blocks to try to gracefully handle any errors.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        --insert/update statements go here
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;    
END CATCH
```

Comment: Good point, you should always have proper error handling to compensate for run-time errors/failures, but in the clean scenario SQL operations are done in the order they are written. That's why it's a scripting language and not object oriented.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I need to start using commit more in general since there is a lack of error handling thru out this DB.
I think the 'go' statement will give me some piece of mind but it sounds like I don't need it.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow- should I be marking both as answers or only the most relevant?